# Trying to disable Variables In-line with Jupyter Code in PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I'd like to be able to disable the variable info being displayed in-line with the code. See the following code and attached screenshot... As you can see, the "In-Line Values" is unchecked, but I still get df2: {DataFrame: (3,3)} at the end. I'm running this as a .ipynb inside of PyCharm.

```py
    #%% md
    ### This code illustrates my problems with in-line values
    
    #%%
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    #%%
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                       columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    df2
```

[image: In-line Values Even With Box Unchecked]

Comment: OT: You can replace that obstrocity with `if i in ("01", "08", "12"...):`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: @Mandera: That statement looks helpful, but I can't tell exactly what it is doing. It looks like "case logic", which I was trying to replicate. Can you link to an example?

Comment: Problem solved. Apparently, Jupyter has a separate place to change this setting: Build, Execution, Deployment | Jupyter | Show inline values in editor.

Comment: Apparently there's a number of related issues on this see [PY-39729](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39729) and [issue 31236](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31236). There's also [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000016220-How-to-disable-automatic-variable-evaluation-when-debugging-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter has a separate place to change this setting. To open settings, press "Ctrl + Alt + s". Then, check under: **Build**, **Execution**, **Deployment** | **Jupyter** | Show inline values in editor.

Answer (score 1):

It took me ages to find it, because for me *it was not* in Build, Execution, Deployment but rather in **Languages & Frameworks > Jupyter > Show inline values in editor**.

`PyCharm 2022.3.2 (Professional Edition)`

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Same in PyCharm 2023. An alternative is to use the search function in the settings and just type "show inline" in the search field, which brings you directly to the right submenu

Answer (score 0):

The relevant documentation for PyCharm states how to get rid of this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/examining-suspended-program.html#inline-view

> Inline values view is enabled by default. To turn it off, in the **Settings/Preferences** dialog `Ctrl+Alt+S`, go to **Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views** and disable the **Show values inline** option.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for trying to help! Unfortunately, that does not fix the problem - I still see pandas dimensions in light grey after the code.

Comment: As an aside, I'm running this in a Jupyter notebook inside of PyCharm. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: I've edited my example above. Please let me know if there's something else I can do to fit the problem!

Comment: @Ren it might help to ask a new question with all that info in order to have more people see it, you might be more likely to get an answer in that case. I don't know if Jupyter would affect things. I notice you have `df2` alone on its own line in the code; I know that's for an example, but to be clear, you're still seeing all values appear in-line in all cases? Also, does it still happen if you're not using a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @RD : Thanks for the follow-up! I actually found the answer, posted it as a comment above. Apparently, Jupyter has a separate place to change this setting: Build, Execution, Deployment | Jupyter | Show inline values in editor

Comment: @Ren you can accept an answer, if there is one, or post an answer yourself and accept it. Since this post is closed, though, you'd have to get it re-opened to be able to add an answer. And since my answer didn't address the problem it wouldn't make sense to mark it as accepted, but you could upvote it if you wanted, since it was helpful, maybe.

Comment: @RD: I upvoted your solution, but it won't show due to my rep score. How do I get the question reopened? I've posted several edits in response to "bad_coder" ... but this question is still marked as closed.

Comment: @Ren unfortunately the question needs enough reopen votes to be reopened, right now it has 2. Unless it gets more visibility it'll probably stay that way. I wouldn't worry too much about it though, I don't think it's a big deal.

Comment: @RandomDavis question seems to be in good shape now, consider casting a reopen vote.

Comment: @bad_coder agreed, I already have voted to reopen.